# Are Comparators newable or injectable objects?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd, comparator

See question in the title! Would you 'inject' or rather 'new' a Comparator? Would you new it if the order of elements is set in the specification and is likely not to change?

Comment: Good question! The answers reveal a wide range of ideas about what injection is fundamentally *for*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question "should I inject this dependency?" is really "should the referring object know about the nature of this dependency?". Er, only negated.

If your class is a `FastestPonyFinder`, and it needs to sort a `List<Pony>` by speed, then i would say it should know about the comparator. The comparator needs to compare by speed, sorting the fastest to the head of the list; no other comparator is suitable for the job. The object should create the comparator, just like it created the `List`.

If your class is a `BestPonyFinder`, then it probably should have the comparator injected, because the definition of what constitutes 'best' is separable from the definition of how to find the pony which meets it. This is going to make your code easier to test and easier to change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Following this train of thought, would you then 'new' a TodaysPoniesFinder into FastestPonyFinder when you know that your application will always work on ponies racing on a specific day? Or would you choose otherwise, considering that TodaysPoniesFinder is probably something more complex than a Comparator? (Please ignore the fact, that one probably would not do something like a 'TodaysPoniesFinder' considering the testablility issues of dates :)). Thanks!

Comment: If the `TodaysPoniesFinder`'s job is to make a list of all ponies competing today, then i would say that the `FastestPonyFinder` does not need to know about what it's doing; it only cares that it produces a list of ponies. Therefore, it should be injected. It should likely be injected as a parameter of some type like 'PonyFinder', rather than the concrete type.

Comment: As an aside, `TodaysPoniesFinder` would be perfectly testable - as long as you inject the value of 'today' into it! This is a [classic move in mockist TDD](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-i-need-to-mock-object-i-cant.html); you typically write some very simple `class Clock { public Date now() { return new Date(); } }` and inject that into any object which needs to know the time. You can then inject a mock instead for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about comparators is that they're *cheap.*  They don't often have any fields, and if they do, they don't have many.

They're so cheap that it doesn't really matter.  You can construct them inline, or get them from a static final field, or get a singleton injection -- who cares?

Comment: From a unit testing perspective, basically your saying that Comparators are cheap, just like getter/setter methods, right? So, you would not consider writing tests for them ...

Comment: Depends.  I'd certainly test the methods that use them.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if there is no state, you can always "reuse" then. In this case they are thread safe and don't get into a state from a previous use. So it in the end really depends on how you implemented the comparator: With state or without.

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing better to have new instance of Comparator, but it doesn't matter if your comparator just implement compare method. If you want inject some data as state to comparator and it changeable use Before and After test methods, to make sure that you not using previous context.